# How to submit a form in Django ModelForm without changing the password value?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-forms, django-authentication

I'm new to Django and want to ask for some advice:

The user information should change in the form, but if I do not fill "`password`" and "`confirm_password`" fields, an empty string is sent to the database. I tried to make changes to the password validator but did not figure out how to send data to the database, without the value of the "password" and "`confirm_password`" fields.

As far as I understand, the most correct thing is to change the save method, but I don't quite understand how to do it correctly.

view.py

```
def change_user_data(request):
    message = ''
    if request.method == "POST":       
        form = ChangeUserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            message = 'Изменения успешно применены!'
    else:
        form = ChangeUserForm(instance=request.user)

    return render(request, 'users/change_user_data.html', context={'form': form, 'message': message})
```

form.py

```
class ChangeUserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    name = forms.CharField(required=False, label="Имя",
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                                            'placeholder': 'name'}))

    surname = forms.CharField(required=False, label="Фамилия",
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                                            'placeholder': 'surname'}))

    nickname = forms.CharField(required=False, label="Псевдоним",
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                                            'placeholder': 'nickname'}))

    email = forms.EmailField(required=False, label="Адрес электронной почты",
                            widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                                        'placeholder':'email'}))

    address = forms.CharField(required=False, label="Адрес",
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                                        'placeholder':'address'}))


    card_id = forms.CharField(required=False, label='Номер банковской карты',
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                                        'placeholder': 'card_id_number'}))

    language = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, label='Язык',
                            choices=(('ua', 'Українська мова'), ('ru', 'Русский язык')),
                            initial='ru',
                            widget=forms.RadioSelect())

    sex = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, label='Пол',
                            choices=(('male', 'Мужской пол'), ('female', 'Женский пол')),
                            widget=forms.RadioSelect())

    phone_number = forms.CharField(required=False, label='Номер телефона',
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                                        'placeholder': 'phone_number'}))

    town = forms.CharField(required=False, label="Город",
                        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                                    'placeholder':'town'}))

    password = forms.CharField(required=False, label='Пароль',
                        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                                        'placeholder':'password'}))
                                            
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(required=False, label='Повторите пароль',
                        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                                        'placeholder':'password'}))


    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        compare_obj = CustomUser.objects.get(email=email)
        if self.instance.pk != compare_obj.pk:
            self.data = self.data.copy()
            self.data['email'] = self.instance.email
            self.add_error('email', f'email {compare_obj.email} занят')
        return email


 

    def clean_confirm_password(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        confirm_password = self.cleaned_data['confirm_password']
        if password != confirm_password:
            self.add_error('confirm_password', 'пароли не совпадают')




    def clean_phone_number(self):
        phone = self.cleaned_data['phone_number']
        if phone == "":
            self.data = self.data.copy()
            self.data['phone_number'] = ""
        elif bool(re.search(r"^((\+38\d{10}$)|(38\d{10})|(\d{10})|(\d{9}))$", phone)) is False:
            self.data = self.data.copy()
            self.data['phone_number'] = self.instance.phone_number
            self.add_error('phone_number', 'Введите номер телефона одного из телефонных операторов Украины ') 
        else:
            if bool(re.search(r"^\+38\d{10}$", phone)) is True:
                phone=phone
            elif bool(re.search(r"^38\d{10}$", phone)) is True: 
                phone = f"+{phone}"
                print(phone)
            elif bool(re.search(r"^\d{10}$", phone)) is True: 
                phone = f"+38{phone}"
            elif bool(re.search(r"^\d{9}$", phone)) is True: 
                phone = f"+380{phone}"

        return phone


    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(ChangeUserForm, self).save(commit=False)
        password = self.cleaned_data["password"]
        print(len(password))
        if len(password) != 0:
            user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
  


    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ("name", "surname", "nickname", "email", "address",
                 "card_id", "language",
                 "sex", "town", "phone_number", "born", "password")

        widgets = {
            'born': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Select a date','type': 'date'})}
```

template:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ message }}

    {% comment %} {{ form.as_p }} {% endcomment %}


    <p>{{ form.name.label_tag }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.name }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.surname.label_tag }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.surname }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.nickname.label_tag }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.nickname }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.email.label_tag }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.email }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.email.errors }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.address.label_tag }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.address }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.card_id.label_tag }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.card_id }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.language.label_tag }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.language }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.sex.label_tag }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.sex }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.phone_number.label_tag }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.phone_number }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.phone_number.errors }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.town.label_tag }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.town }}</p>

    <p>{{ form.born.label_tag }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.born }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.born.errors }}</p>

    <p>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.password }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.password.errors }}</p>


    <p>{{ form.confirm_password.label_tag }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.confirm_password }}</p>


    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Submit</button>

</form>
```

I read other threads, but, unfortunately, I did not find the answer to my question. I would really appreciate your help =)

Answer (score 0):

Your request method should be PUT or PATCH, not POST. Post creates new data, meaning if you don't fill in a field, it will be empty. PATCH and PUT are request methods for updating data. Specifically, PATCH only changes the fields you input, leaving other fields untouched. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @tumpa02, but:
Unfortunately, as I know, Django don't support PUT or PATCH methots =(
When I try to use it in command line i see:

`"GET /users/change_user_data/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=p6VOvZLTEHTpkWIyxkDK1yilCIwmauPwXz8ZwMjh396WUsUxH102lLDCb453e3wW&name=dsdsds&surname=&nickname=&email=user123%40gmail.com&address=&card_id=&language=ru&phone_number=&town=&born=&password=&confirm_password= HTTP/1.1" 200 12820`